# Kotlin long literal: The value is out of range

Tags: kotlin

bit mask `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaL` (16a's) is out or range in kotlin. If I have Android Sutdio automatically convert from Java, it translate to `-0x5555555555555556L`, which is `101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010110`, it is now only 63 bit and 0110 at the end is off.

`0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaL` works well in Java. I need an explanation of why it becomes `-0x5555555555555556L` in kotlin.
Another question is how does kotlin represent negative Long? Why the - sign in the front? It is not 2's complement like in Java?

I looked at the doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#literal-constants, I know kotlin support Hexadecimals syntax.

I also tried Unsigned Long `val mask2: ULong = 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaL` same problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-0x5555555555555556L` is correct, btw. The binary you printed is that negative value in base 2 (not 2s complement), without the leading minus sign. The 2s complement representation is `1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010`.  So Android studio was correct.

Comment: It's a strange problem in the Kotlin programming language. There is a bug report here (JetBrains bug tracker for Kotlin): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Java's parsing:

```kotlin
val x: Long = java.lang.Long.parseUnsignedLong("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 16)
println(x)    // Outputs -6148914691236517206
```

You can look [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4749) for some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin doesn't let you create literal values greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, but you can declare an unsigned long and convert it to a long with he same binary value like this:

```
val long = 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaau.toLong()
```

Example:

```
fun main() {
    val long = 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaau.toLong()
    println(long.toString(16))
    println(long.toString(2))
    println(long.toULong().toString(16))
    println(long.toULong().toString(2))
}
```

Output:

```
-5555555555555556
-101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010110
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why that literal works in Java is because Java's hexadecimal integer literals can represent negative numbers, and `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaL` just so happens to fit 64 bits. From the [JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> A hexadecimal numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters 0x or 0X followed by one or more ASCII hexadecimal digits interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

> It is a compile-time error if a hexadecimal, octal, or binary long literal does not fit in 64 bits.

(Note that decimal literals in Java OTOH can only represent non-negative integers).

So in Java, `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaL` doesn't represent the positive number

```
12297829382473034410
```

After all, `Long` in both languages only has the max value of

```
9223372036854775807
```

It instead represents the negative number

```
-6148914691236517206
```

You can see that this is the case in Java by printing the number in hex:

```
long a = 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaL;
System.out.println(Long.toString(a, 16));
// -5555555555555556
// this is the same hex you get when you translate to Kotlin!
```

Kotlin's hexadecimal literals don't represent negative integers, so `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaL` is out of range, because it represents 12297829382473034410, rather than -6148914691236517206.

Comment: thank you, since I am just using it as bit mask, I don't really care about its numeric value.
0xaaaa is intuitive enough for me to come up with, converting it to -5555.. by hand is a bit .. unusual

Comment: @BabyishTank I agree that this is a problem when you just want to do a bit mask. The bug report that enzo linked addresses this.

Comment: Is this also why -9223372036854775808L is out of range, despite it being the actual value of Long.MIN_VALUE?

Comment: @AndroidKotlinNoob Correct. That is applying the minus operator on a literal that is out of range.